# Objective-C JSON Parse don't work in other classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, nsurlconnection

I have a strange problem with the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate.
I have created a class for parsing of json.
Here the code:

```
- (void)createJSONDictionaryFromURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    (void)[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    jsonData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{ 
    [jsonData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Fail with error");
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    self.jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.jsonDictionary);
}
```

In the Method connectionDidFinishLoading, is everything correct, the console shows the correct data.
But I want to use this in the viewDidLoad Method from my ViewController.

```
JSONParser *parser = [[JSONParser alloc] init];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[parser createJSONDictionaryFromURL:url];
dict = parser.jsonDictionary;

NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

The console shows (null), can anybody help me?

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JSONParser` is asynchronous because of the network connection (it is asynchronous). So, when you currently call `parser.jsonDictionary` you see that the data isn't ready yet.

You don't want to try blocking until the data is available, rather you should setup a callback to get the data to your view controller when it's ready (so you can save it and update the UI).

That could be done by adding a `delegate` property to your `JSONParser` and having the view controller assign itself and implement some callback method. Or, using less code, the `JSONParser` can offer a block property that the view controller sets and which is called in `connectionDidFinishLoading:` (make sure the `@property` uses (copy, nonatomic)`).